# loop over names of several pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of `DataFrames` from different files, which are named for example df001, df002 and so on. 
Now I want to loop over those DataFrames to execute similar tasks. But I can't figure out how to address them.

This failed (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'):

```
names = ['df001', 'df002']

for name in names:
    name.iloc[1,1]
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Failed'. keep in mind that loc will raise a keyError if the index 1 and column 1 don't exist in all of the dataframes

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous. The problem is not the .iloc (this was just an example for the 'similar tasks').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
names = [df001, df002]

for name in names:
    name.iloc[1,1]
```

Comment: No worries. Please upvote and accept it as your answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the string name for purposes other than looping, you can always store the dataframes in a dictionary:

```
d = {'df001': df001, 'df002': df002}

for name in d:
    d[name].iloc[1, 1]
```